# Where to find a list of the computer stored in the FICS Games Database?

Tags: engines, database

According to the [FICS Games Database](https://www.ficsgames.org/) there are currently 1,525 "computers stored". Such accounts are indicated by a "(C)" after the username. However, this suffix does not seem to be recorded in the database.

There is an outdated list here: https://www.freechess.org/Help/HelpFiles/computer_list.html.

Where do I find a recent, complete list of the usernames of all 1525 "computers stored"?

Comment: I do not think you are going to just find a list. You can connect to the FICS, and use the "who C" command, but that only shows computers actually logged in at the moment. From that database page you linked, you can also search for games of "computers only" or "humans and computers", and it will return a list of games played by computers, and you could then start to form a list, but there is still no guarantee that you would get a complete list, and it might take a lot of work. Good luck.

Comment: To add to what PhishMaster says, you could download the pgns of all games played on FICS, and search for the fields [WhiteIsComp "Yes"] or [BlackIsComp "Yes"]. You can then extract from the White or Black fields the names of the computers who have played on FICS.